# Bcoin wallet always has unconfirmed balance

Tags: bcoin

I have locally running `bcoin` node in `testnet` and acquired test bitcoins through faucet. Now, when calling balance check via `bcoin cli wallet balance` (when synchronization completed) I always receiving following result:

```
{
  "wid": 1,
  "id": "primary",
  "account": -1,
  "unconfirmed": 550722654,
  "confirmed": 550722654
}
```

I see that wallet contains amount but a bit confused that `unconfirmed` field contains the same value as `confirmed` one. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

This probably helps you:

https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/issues/163

> What we really needed was a "real-time" balance, and "confirmed" balance.
>   So the simplest solution was:
>   confirmed = what is on the blockchain
>   unconfimed = what is on blockchain + mempool
>   Essentially unconfirmed is your real-time balance. confirmed is your blockchain-secured balance.